# Setting up "Hot reload" for frontend assets

Tags: configuration, continuous-delivery

We would like to improve the frontend development experience in our Sitecore 9.2 solution and provide something like "hot reload", i.e. the frontend is built auto-magically and published to wwwroot, such that our frontend developers does not have to wait for the website to startup after each change to the frontend assets.

**Background**

We use webpack for our sass + javascript + react components.

We do **not** use Sitecore JSS.

Our Visual Studio solution is following Helix conventions (multiple small projects!).

Currently, our backend and frontend development process is following these steps:

1. Manually compile code (backend + frontend)
2. Manually publish to wwwroot
3. Wait for app pool recycle
4. Site startup

**Question**
Does anyone have experience configuring "hot reload" for frontend development in a Sitecore solution, that they want to share?

Answer (score 5):

For local testing of frontend code there is usually no need for building/publishing the visual studio solution. For your local dev environment, you have several options that will be a lot faster:

## A) Symlink from Frontend build-dir to webroot

Set up a symbolic link in the local webroot and point that directory to the output of the frontend build. With webpack this would typically be a bundle in the /dist dir.

Example:

```
mklink /D "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-project.local\assets\mybundle" "c:\dev\myproject\dist\mybundle"
```

Make sure your assets are not cached by IIS throuhg web.config (only locally):

```
<configuration>
<location path="assets/mybundle">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

## B) Use Nginx as local proxy

If your frontend project supports self-hosting, you can bypass requests to http://my-project.local/assets/mybundle to your self-hosted webserver i.E. http://localhost:1234

nginx.conf:

```
server {
   listen       88;
   server_name  my-project.local;

   location /assets/mybundle/ {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:1234/dist/mybundle;
   }        
}
```

Now you can access the local site using:

```
http://my-project.local:88
```

Requests to frontend resources will be redirected to the self-hosted webserver.

## C) xCopy command in conjunction with file watcher

First, set up a batch file for copying your frontend bundle to the IIS webroot i.E.

```
xcopy "c:\dev\myproject\dist\mybundle\*.*" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\my-project.local\assets\mybundle"  /sy
```

Then set up a file watcher in the frontend build folder i.E. with this powershell script: https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created

## General: Referencing frontend assets

A general challenge with all of these options is referencing the generated .js and .css files in razor layouts. Webpack typically generates hash codes in the file names like

```
main.8cd6d964582176f0ac47.js
```

A possible solution is to update hashes at runtime based on the files in the bundle directory:

```
public static IHtmlString Asset(this HtmlHelper helper, string content)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(content);
    var fileParts = fileName?.Split('.');

    if (fileName == null || fileParts.Length != 2)
    {
        return new HtmlString(content);
    }

    var extension = Path.GetExtension(content);
    var firstPart = fileParts.FirstOrDefault();

    var actualFileName = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/assets/mybundle/"), $"*{extension}").FirstOrDefault(f => Path.GetFileName(f).Split('.').FirstOrDefault() == firstPart);
    return new HtmlString(actualFileName);
}
```

In Razor views:

```
<script src="@Html().Asset('main.js')"></script>
```

I would only do this locally for performance reasons.

## Summary:

These are just a few of many options. Personally, I have found option **A (Symlink)** to be the best if the frontend framework supports live building. Otherwise option **B (Local Proxy)** works best.

In any case, Frontend changes are immediately visible on the local site and no AppPool recycle is required. This greatly speeds up the frontend development process.

Comment: Wow! I only tested the first solution (A), since I dont have Nginx available, but that worked just perfect.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On top of the answer from Mark Lowe, also ensure that View Precompilation is done, and ensure the front end build / watch task copies the CSHTML file across to the web site.

This is the setting I have. Take a look at the environment that I have introduced which I labelled as LocalDeveloper.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:localenv="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/localenv/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
<sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <mvc>
        <precompilation>
            <assemblies>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ACME.Website" />
            </assemblies>
        </precompilation>
    </mvc>
    <settings localenv:require="LocalDeveloper">
        <setting name="Mvc.UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer" value="true" />
    </settings>
</sitecore>
```